# Builiding a selection from a Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i want to build a selection from a dataframe based on double search-arguments. In detail:

I have build a search within a given Dataframe based on one value. This value can be given multiple times. The difference can be found in the row of the value. Here is a example:

```
TECHNIKART  FSZ               BEZEICHNUNG                       FIRMA           PRODUKT_SPANNUNG     KLIMA             EW_KW                 MENGE_KW LEISTUNG_KW       Ü
```

I get this Dataframe from following search in a bigger Dataframe:

```
key = '71E'
try:
    geraet_dat2 = geraet_dat[geraet_dat.FSZ == key]
    lang = len(geraet_dat2.index)
    print(geraet_dat2)
```

My idea is now to have a if-else-query based on the length of the Dataframe. If the Dataframe has the lenght 1 i will print the values of the needed cells. If the Dataframe is longer than 1 the following popup appears:

```
def abfrage_selektion():
    popup_selektion = Tk()
    frame_selek = Frame(popup_selektion)
    frame_selek.pack()
    popup_selektion.configure(bg="Snow2")
    popup_selektion.geometry('300x250')
    popup_selektion.title('Bitte Gerät auswählen!')

    LABEL_SELEKTION = LabelFrame(popup_selektion, text="Bitte Gerät auswählen: ")
    LABEL_SELEKTION.place(x = 2, y = 2, width = 296, height = 246)
    INFO = ttk.Label(LABEL_SELEKTION, justify=CENTER, text="Diese FSZ ist mehrfach verfügbar! \nBitte das entsprechende Gerät wählen!")
    INFO.place(x = 50, y = 5)
    SEPTR_1 = ttk.Separator(LABEL_SELEKTION, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    SEPTR_1.place(x = 5, y = 40, width = 280)
    GERAET = ttk.LabelFrame(LABEL_SELEKTION, text="Geräte: ")
    GERAET.place(x = 15, y = 50, width = 260, height = 120)
    LISTE = Listbox(GERAET, yscrollcommand=True)
    LISTE.insert(1, '1')
    LISTE.insert(2, '2')
    LISTE.insert(3, '3')
    LISTE.insert(4, '4')
    LISTE.place(x = 5, y = 2, width = 240, height = 90)
    SEPTR_2 = ttk.Separator(LABEL_SELEKTION, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    SEPTR_2.place(x = 5, y = 180, width = 280)
    BUTTON_OK = ttk.Button(LABEL_SELEKTION, text="OK")
    BUTTON_OK.place(x = 5, y = 190, width = 280, height = 30)
```

that far everything is nice an clear for me.

But now the point i dont know how to solve:
In the popup i want a selection from the given Dataframe with more than one Dataset to select the wanted Data. The criteria for the selection should be 'BEZEICHNUNG' and 'PRODUKT_SPANNUNG'.

Do you have any ideas how i can do this? I searched in the web but didnt find a good solution for that.

Thank you for you help!

Comment: I think you need Tkinter tag if need create selects.

Comment: sorry i dont know what you mean?!

Comment: Do you need change `geraet_dat2 = geraet_dat[geraet_dat.FSZ == key]` to add new conditions or create new selections in `Tkinter` which call conditions?

Comment: why should i? i get the selection from that condition. I want to have the output(the 4 different datasets) in a selection... do you understand what i mean?

Comment: I am not sure. Problem is create conditions in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) like `geraet_dat[(geraet_dat.FSZ == key) & (geraet_dat.PRODUKT_SPANNUNG.isin(['48V / 60V','48V / 60V  16'])]` ?

Comment: ah ok its a missunderstanding.. sure i have to select that data on this two criteria but my problem is that is dont know how to put that in the selection..

Comment: So my comment was helpful?

Comment: partly.. the main question is how i get the Data in the selection...